# Как с помощью RegExp отфильтровать артикул товара (#КЛП1483П1)?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть артикул товара (#КЛП1483П1). Нужно отфильтровать скобки в начале и в конце артикула, а также знак # . Выражение вида `/\(\#^.*$\)/` не срабатывает (функция `preg_match`).
Не подскажете правильное выражение для данного примера?

Comment: `'/^\(#.*\)$/'`

Comment: Не фильтрует, артикул остается как есть.

Comment: Что не фильтрует? Я не вижу кода который бы что-то фильтровал

Comment: Прочитай [mcve] например.

Comment: `'/[^(#]*[\d]/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?
$text = "(#КЛП1483П1)";
$regex = "/(?<=^\(#)[^)]+/";
preg_match($regex,$text,$out);

print_r($out);
?>
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => КЛП1483П1
)
```

Сначала позитивный просмотр назад без захвата символов `(?<=^\(#)` - откусываем `(#`, потом захват всех 1+ символов, кроме закрывающей скобки, т.е. откусываем `)`.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно :)